# array do php para json não vai todos os dados

Tags: php, json, array, mysqli

Olá , estou tendo um problema com meu código e queria a ajuda de vocês.

Preciso pegar dados de uma tabela e mandar como json, tenho 10 itens  na minha tabela porém o json só manda um.

Tabela: local

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu código onde coloco todo o PHP e Msqli

```
include("connect.php");

header("Content-Type: application/json");

$queryString =  "SELECT * FROM `local`";   

$query = mysqli_query($conexao, $queryString) or die(mysqli_error());

$paises = array();

while ($pais = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $paises['paises'] = $pais['paises'];

}

echo json_encode($paises);
```

E ele só me retorna o ultimo item que é a "argentina" e foi o máximo que consegui pois já tentei de varias maneiras. se puderem me ajudar ai eu agradeço.

Comment: Exiba o resultado do array json com um `print_r()` pra ver o que está sendo exibido. print_r(json_encode($paises));

Answer (score 0):

Retorne assim:

```
$paises = array();
//EDIÇÃO  while ($pais = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn, $query)) {
while ($pais = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $paises[] = array(
        "paises" => $pais['paises'];
    );

}

echo json_encode($paises);
```

Porque do jeito que você está enviando está só substituindo o valor.

Comment: Faltou fechar o parênteses do `array`. E por que não utilizar a função `mysqli_fetch_all`?

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo ele continua recebendo  um valor no json. e Anderson como poderia usar esse mysqli_fetch_all?

Comment: @MarlonYago talvez não funcionou porque o @adventistaam colocou um parâmetro `$conn` a mais na chamada da função. Mantenha apenas o parâmetro `$query` tal como você fez na pergunta. Sobre a `mysqli_fetch_all`, veja a [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss está correto.. isso mesmo

Comment: também é recomendável que mysqli_error tenha a conexão mysqli_error($conexao)

Answer (score -1):

Obrigado a todos, consegui resolver o problema

```
$paises = array();

while ($pais = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

$paises[] = $pais['paises'];

}

echo json_encode($paises);
```

E mudei o DB que era o principal problema

Comment: A resposta é basicamente a mesma que a outra, então por quê postá-la novamente? Se a resposta lhe foi útil, vote positivamente na mesma e marque-a utilizando o ícone **✓** no lado esquerdo da resposta. Para mais informações, faça o [tour].